# Hooking/Scraping .NET application

Tags: automation, screen-scraping, hook, gdi

I would like to create a trading bot for Magic Online. If it's a concern, doing that would not violate the terms of use, and several vendors for such a bot exist. I initially started out with the DLL injection/API hooking path, but that doesn't work as it doesn't seem to call any of the standard GDI functions. My code works fine on Notepad, but does nothing on MTGO_NET. Same result with third party hooking libraries.

I then "gave up", and decided to try to use OCR. However, this weird thing happens when I try to do a screenshot of the client window: I only get the game's splash screen, no matter what the client is actually displaying. The main window device context is always the splash screen. I am guessing the client uses a separate device context to actually render the game, and I have to somehow figure out what that DC is. Does anyone have experience encountering this issue? I would gladly take any advice regarding either hooking .NET applications or how to take a screenshot.

I am testing all this on Windows Vista Ultimate 64 bit. I haven't tested this on a 32 bit installation, but I hope that isn't an issue.

Comment: I figured out the reason why the screenshot functionality wasn't working. It was because of desktop composition. Once I turned it off for the application, copying the device context content works fine.

Comment: A question downvote without an explanation in the comment is stupid :( who was that? who was that? :\

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look here: http://www.mtgnews.com/showthread.php?t=191879

Which provides a link to source code for a 'working' bot.

The result of a google search............

Comment: I would vote you down if I could. The link brings you to a pay site. Not even mentioning the fact that the bot in question isn't a full-functionality version.

Comment: Hazerider, you need to develop your reading abilities if you want people to help you on this site. The bot I linked to has full functionality, with the change of 2 lines of source code. The link may well be a pay site, yet in your original question you made no mention that you explicitly did not want to pay. Unlike you, I can downvote, but I am not that childish. Other's have already spoken.

Comment: The bot does not have the functionality that allows you to set a price list for different cards. It only allows you to trade X cards for Y tickets. Your response implies that I just came to stackoverflow and posted a question without bothering to google. I googled this issue (and various related techniques) extensively. In addition, whoever voted me down isn't providing anyone with any value without explaining what isn't clear and what isn't useful. If he didn't understand what I am talking about (using GDI for hooking/scraping in either C++ or C#), that's his short-coming, not mine.

Comment: Uhm...in the communication model I learned in school, when A sends a message to B, and B does not get the intended meaning of the message, it is ALWAYS A's fault, and due to the way A sent the message. Now, 30-and-some-years later, I still tend to agree after some thinking.